# Will connecting two hubs with two cables help for performance?

Tags: networking, switch, hub

I have two 1 GBit hubs and I wondering if connecting them with two network cables help for network performance?

Here is example: 
I have switch **A** and **B**. I have 4 computers, **A1** and **A2** which are connected to switch **A**, **B1** and **B2** connected to switch **B**. **A1** is copying some files over the network from **B1** and also **A2** starts getting some data from **B2**. Can this copying be done faster if I connect my switches with two cables?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain MORE? What is your network setup..What made you ask this question

Comment: @Sickest I will update my post. I am asking this question because I don't know the answer.

Comment: @Sickest see my update. I hope that helps to understand the situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for you to see any performance increase by plugging in two cables between the switches, you need to set up something called link aggregation, which will increase throughput between the two switches, and also provide redundancy if one of the links fail.

Link aggregation is not supported by unmanaged switches, you need a managed or websmart switch.

[Here is an example on how to set up link aggregation between two switches.](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-howto/30556-how-to-set-up-switch-link-aggregation)

As noted by davidgo in the comments, plugging in two cables between switches without using link aggregation is actually a terrible idea.

Smarter switches (ie, running STP - spanning tree protocol) will hopefully realise whats going on and disable one of the two links. Dumber switches may get confused and start sending the traffic in a loop between the two switches, which is a great way to make your network turn into a notwork!

Comment: Good answer.  Its worth noting that if done without link aggregation, plugging multiple cables between switches can cause routing loops and hurt a network (painfully if its not running some variant of STP)

Comment: @davidgo Excellent point, have edited that into my answer. That could definitely get bad quickly

Answer (score 0):

simple answer is: No.

If you have 2 switches, only **one** connection needs to be made between the 2 switches in order to have a connection, Adding another (wire) connection between the 2 switches will not increase performance.

It might even cause problems? But this is purely speculation cause I've never tested such a thing.

If you're looking to increase performance, Buy 2 gigabite switches instead. And make sure all the nic cards support Gb transfer.

Comment: `It might even cause problems?`  It will absolutely cause problems.  It will create a loop unless the switches support spanning tree, or are configured for some form of link aggregation (enterprise switches).